# EeePc Fn buttons don't work out of the box

Tags: 10.10, 10.04, eeepc

Some of the Fn key combinations don't work on my EeePc 1005HAB.

They control important functions such as:

- volume up, down, and mute
- sleep
- launch task manager
- external monitor toggle
- WiFi on/off
- track-pad on/off
- back-light on/off

The only buttons that do work are the screen brightness up and down. This would be a great little net-book for Ubuntu if only these function keys and track-pad button would work.

Update: I have tried to install `eeepc-acpi-scripts` from the software center but it wont install and returns an error:

Package dependencies cannot be resolved.

Update: After trying to install `eeepc-acpi-scripts` to no avail I searched lanchpad and found this bug [#262679](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/acpi/+bug/262679). In comment [#35](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/acpi/+bug/262679/comments/35) [fioghual](https://launchpad.net/~fioghual) writes:

> I don't know if I'm correct, but in my case, after doing some research, it proves unnecessary to install it.
>   What solves everything is:
>
> `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
>
> replace:
>   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
>   with:
>   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"
>
> and then:
>   
>   `sudo update-grub`

After some testing I found that this solution works perfectly on 10.04 but after an upgrade to 10.10 the process must be repeated again. In 10.10 everything works except the track-pad on/off and the back-light on/off. Does anyone know how to fix this? Typing is much more difficult if the track-pad is on.

Comment: Just wondering, is it alright to include what I find in my question when I edit it, or should I answer my own question?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to install `eeepc-acpi-scripts`

```
sudo apt-get install eeepc-acpi-scripts
```

and see if that helps (after a reboot).

Comment: I've tried that already but I get an error that says: Package dependencies cannot be resolved.

Comment: Found a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/acpi/+bug/262679

Comment: More like this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/505452

Answer (score 1):

Try with [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/05/control-your-eeepc-and-assign-custom-fn.html) and [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/05/enable-fn-keys-on-your-asus-eeepc-and.html) posts on WebUpd8.

Comment: The second Link looks similar to what I found.